# Horizontal dashed line between items in ngFor

Tags: css, angular, ngfor

I am using ngFor for displaying a list of items which are separated by a horizontal dashed line as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of comments;let lastItem = last;">
 <div class="comment-box">
   <div class="comment-author">{{comment.createdBy}}</div>
   <div class="creation-date">{{comment.createdOn}}</div>
   <div class="comment-text">{{comment.text}}</div>
 </div>
 <div class="dashed-line-box" *ngIf="!lastItem">
   <hr class="new1">
 </div>
</div>

.dashed-line-box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 320px;
  height: 16px;

 border-style: solid;// to outline the container box
 border-width: thin;
}

hr.new1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 8px;
  border-top: 1px dashed;
}
```

I can see rectangles for each dashed-line-box entry, but they dont contain horizontal like I am expecting.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have applied dashed-line-box class to div so it create rectangle, just remove the class from div and try

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a dashed border style in `<hr>`

```
hr.new1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 8px;
    border-top: 1px dashed blue;
    width: 100%;
}
```

or if you want a dashed border on outer div try below code

```
.dashed-line-box {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 320px;
    height: 16px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

css property `border-style: solid;` from class `.dashed-line-box` is putting the box in the last line;To get a horizontal bar, you need to remove `position:absolute` from the class `hr.new1`;

relevant css:

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.dashed-line-box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 320px;
  height: 16px;

 /* border-style: solid;*/
 border-width: thin;
}

hr.new1 {

  margin-top: 8px;
  border-top: 1px dashed;
}
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qn1avb)

Comment: Thanks.It worked partially. I have 3 elements in list. I get line after 2nd element but not first.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need hr when you can achieve this using `border bottom` property. Just add one class to parent div and use border bottom.

```css
.box {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" *ngFor="let comment of comments;let lastItem = last;">
 <div class="comment-box">
   <div class="comment-author">{{comment.createdBy}}</div>
   <div class="creation-date">{{comment.createdOn}}</div>
   <div class="comment-text">{{comment.text}}</div>
 </div>

</div>
```